# Solving two equations for two unknown in terms of two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have the two equation $ac - bd = 1$ and $ad + bc = 0$. How can I solve these two equations for $c$ and $d$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use substitution.  From the first, $c=\frac {1+bd}a$.  Plug that into the second and solve for $d$.

Answer (score 0):

For this one, you can use *Cramer's formulae* (not recommended in the general case). The augmented matrix of the system (with $c, d$ as unknowns) is
$$\begin{bmatrix}\!\!\!\begin{array}{rr|r}a&-b&1\\b&a&0\end{array}\!\!\!\end{bmatrix}, $$ 
hence the solutions, if the determinant of the system $D=a^2+b^2$ is non-zero, are
$$c=\frac{\begin{bmatrix}\!\!\!\begin{array}{rr|r}1&-b\\0&a\end{array}\!\!\!\end{bmatrix}}{D}=\frac a{a^2+b^2},\qquad d= \frac{\begin{bmatrix}\!\!\!\begin{array}{rr|r}a&1\\b&0\end{array}\!\!\!\end{bmatrix}}{D}=-\frac b{a^2+b^2}.$$
No solution on $\mathbf R$ if $a^2+b^2=0$, since it implies $a=b=0$. On $\mathbf C$, if $a^2+b^2=0$, $a$, hence $b\ne 0$, the system has rank $1$ and  is equivalent to the unique equation $ad+bc=0$, whence 
$$d=-\frac{bc}a=\pm\frac{iac}a=\pm ic.$$